# Rendering fetch response with React

Tags: json, reactjs, webpack, fetch-api

I've been trying to render data from /src/data.json using the fetch api to my react component, although I receive a 404 every time. But, devtools gives me the error 'GET http://localhost:8000/src/data.json 404 (Not Found)'. Any ideas on what the cause could be?

```
var ContentComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        fetch('./src/data.json')
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response); //check for response
        });
        return (
            <h1>{this.response}</h1>
        );
    }
});
```

I thought this could be a webpack issue? That maybe webpack isn't grabbing the json file for the bundle? Then again, my bundle is valid, but I get 10 errors in my main.js which I'm guessing are related to this 404. But I'm not completely sure since this is my first WebPack experience, and first non-tutorial react experience.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you actually open `http://localhost:8000/src/data.json` and get the JSON?
Your data.json should probably come from the build folder rather than 'src'

Comment: If you're trying to load local json data, no need to fetch it. just import it using the json loader https://github.com/webpack/json-loader

Comment: That sure did it! Thanks. But why does it work this way? Is it because webpack/react only see this as external data, and not something to bundle in? Does that make sense?

Comment: @azium That seems like a much better approach. Thanks!